# Avoiding state mutation in a recursive function (Redux)

Tags: javascript, recursion, reactjs, immutability, redux

I'm building a web app using React and Redux and I have come up against a problem regarding state immutability.

My state looks similar to this: -

```
{
    tasks: [
        {
            id: 't1',
            text: 'Task 1',
            times: {
                min: 0,
                max: 0
            },
            children: [
                { id: 't1c1', text: 'Task 1 child 1', times: { min: 2, max: 3 }, children: [] },
                { id: 't1c2', text: 'Task 1 child 2', times: { min: 3, max: 4 }, children: [] }
                ...
            ]
        }
        ...
    ]
}
```

This defines a hierarchy of "task" objects with each task having zero or more child tasks in the "children" array. Each task also has a "times" object which records the minimum ("min") and maximum ("max") times (in hours) that this task will take.

I created a simple recursive function which is used to traverse the tasks hierarchy and calculate and set the total "times" values (min and max) for all tasks that have one or more children. So in the example above as it stands, the task "t1" should have a min time of 5 (2 + 3) and a max time of 7 (3 + 4) after the calculation. This function of course needs to be recursive in nature as each task can have an arbitrary number of ancestors.

(the following was written from memory without testing so please ignore/forgive any typos)

```
function taskTimes(tasks)
{
    let result = { min: 0, max: 0 };

    if (tasks.length === 0)
        return result;

    tasks.forEach(task => {
        if (task.children.length > 0)
        {
            let times = taskTimes(task.children);
            task.times.min = times.min; // MUTATING!
            task.times.max = times.max; // MUTATING!
            result.min += times.min;
            result.max += times.max;
        }
        else
        {
            result.min += task.times.min;
            result.max += task.times.max;
        }
    });

    return result;
}
```

The function I created works correctly but I knew before I wrote it that I would have a problem: while traversing the tasks hierarchy, individual task objects (specifically the "times" objects) are mutated. This is a problem because I want to run this in a reducer, and therefore I want to create a new state from this action rather than mutating it.

My question therefore is, what is the best way to modify this system in order to avoid mutating the state?

I could try using Immutable.js to enforce immutability throughout the hierarchy, and attempting this is probably my next step. Another option is not to store this data at all, but to calculate it in each  component when necessary. While the latter is probably a cleaner option, I still want to know how best to tackle this as I can foresee having to do something similar to this in other projects and for peace of mind I would like to solve the problem now.

Any advice for best practises in this area would be greatly appreciated. Also, if I have overlooked something very obvious then please be kind! 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think the most common best practice is to flatten your data structure, like relational tables. This way its much easier to return new states without needing to mutate inner keys & arrays. Normalizr is a very popular tool to help with this https://github.com/paularmstrong/normalizr

Comment: Yes, this is definitely a good call, especially when data becomes linked and in need of normalisation.  Perhaps having each entity (task) in an object with its own key would make creating a copy simpler too, I will have to check it out.  I hadn't seen normalizr before so thanks for the link too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your second assumption is right. Your should store as little as possible data in your store. Data that can be computed should be computed on the fly. If you're making some heavy computations (like recursive ones as above) you should take a look to [redux-reselect](https://github.com/reactjs/reselect), a tiny library to create memoized selectors to compute derivated data from your store.

Comment: I agree, and thanks for pointing me towards redux-reselect.  It seems like a nice solution to computing data with cached results so I will definitely give it a try and I'm sure this is the kind of method I will ultimately use in the project.

Answer (score 2):

If your intention is NOT to manipulate the state it would be a quick & dirty workaround to create a copy where it doesn´t matter if you manipulate it while calculating the result. 
If your intention is to update all times of the child tasks with that function a simple way is to create a (deep) copy of the state, manipulate and return it.

For example a snippet of the reducer:

```js
...
switch(action.type) {
  case actions.RECALCULATE_TASK_COUNT:
    var nextState = $.extend({}, state);
    taskTimes(nextState);
    return nextState;
  ...

}
...

function taskTimes(tasks)
{
    let result = { min: 0, max: 0 };

    if (tasks.length === 0)
        return result;

    tasks.forEach(task => {
        if (task.children.length > 0)
        {
            let times = taskTimes(task.children);
            task.times.min = times.min; // MUTATING!
            task.times.max = times.max; // MUTATING!
            result.min += times.min;
            result.max += times.max;
        }
        else
        {
            result.min += task.times.min;
            result.max += task.times.max;
        }
    });

    return result;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, yes I had thought about creating a deep copy of the array prior to updating it in-place with the recursive function.I had attempted to do the same by composing a series of shallow copies but I had no success initially.  Thanks for pointing out that jQuery (and I assume lodash's merge()) methods provide deep copy functionality.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, thanks to Pcriulan for providing an answer which goes towards a proper solution to this problem, and thanks to Deton for providing a possible solution to the theoretical problem.

I thought I would share the eventual solution that I created. As Pcriulan noted, this is probably not the best way to solve this in a real-world application however I wanted to show this solution here as it solves the theoretical problem.

So my solution involves modifying the recursive function so that it acts in a similar way to a reducer itself, specifically in that it will return a copy of the tasks array (and child arrays) of either new or unmodified task objects based on whether their attributes were modified or not. Therefore, it provides a deep copy of only objects that have been modified, so it should be relatively efficient. My unit tests also show that the state is now not mutated by the function, so that solves the initial problem.

The updated function is: -

```
function getTaskTime(tasks)
{
    let result = { min: 0, max: 0, tasks: [] };

    if (tasks.length === 0)
        return result;

    // Build a new tasks array
    result.tasks = tasks.map(task => {

        if (task.children.length > 0)
        {
            // Get times and new task array for task.children
            const child_result = getTaskTime(task.children);

            // Add child times to current totals
            result.min += child_result.min;
            result.max += child_result.max;

            // Return new task object with new child array and modified times
            return Object.assign({}, task, {
                time: { min: child_result.min, max: child_result.max },
                children: child_result.tasks
            });
        }
        else
        {
            // If task has no children, simply add times to current totals and return
            // the unmodified task object
            result.min += task.time.min;
            result.max += task.time.max;
            return task;
        }

    });

    return result;
}
```

Hopefully this will help others facing a similar situation.  Feel free to comment if there are any improvements to be made or problems that I have missed.